# Postgres : Like search where data is encrypted at column level

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption

I have a Postgresql db of version 9.4.1 to be very specific. Values of certain columns of some table are encrypted, now i have scenario where i need to use such encrypted columns in where condition with like pattern. To encrypt data under columns i am used AES encryption scheme and doing encryption() and decryption() on java side only, so now my database is not aware of what plaintext values are stored.

Above logic works perfectly for exact search but LIKE search is failing here

For example: Let's say data under customername column of customer table is encrypted and i want to perform like search on customername as follows.

```
select customer_id from customer where customername like '%'+encryption(ABC)+'%'
```

Comment: You have it the other way around. The query should be something along the lines of `select customer_id from customer where decryption(customername) like '%'+ABC+'%'`

Comment: Don't think such search is possible at all: Postgres knows nothing about encrypted data if encryption completed on Java side. So for Postgres and his 'LIKE' query encrypted data is just very long line.   Maximum what you can  do without decryption is to encrypt search query on Java side , but that will work only for exact match.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i am finding it hard to understand how decryption(customername) syntax will work since decryption() is a java function

Comment: @DarkKnight of course it is, and that's the problem Alex is pointing out. The fact is, if you do it like you wanted to, you'll be comparing the encrypted version of a string, which has no bearing on a similarity between the decrypted strings. So, for example, suppose that "Hello world" encrypted is "sonteuhsanuaunoea" and "Hello" encrypted is "pc,.lgpr'ryf,.y,lrp.". If you try to do something like `'sonteuhsanuaunoea' like '%' + encryption('Hello') + '%'` (if it was possible) you won't get the result you expect.

Comment: If that is the case do you guys see any workaround this, any suggestions regarding how it can be done by other means and not doing it the way i am trying to do ?

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes. Don't encrypt data that you want to match via `LIKE` or similar operators.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker i already went through this link, details here are very abstract and does not relate to posgresql

Comment: You can keep a decrypted copy of you table in memory and perform all operations in memory.

Comment: @Beetlejuice Number of records in DB is quite hugh, am not sure i can have so many records in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post evaluating multiple suggested options, i finally concluded issue using Pgcrypto module of postgres. pgcrypto allows like search too, only drawback here is length of column needs to increased.

Details of Pgcrypto module are available  here.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/pgcrypto.html

Comment: This is a complete example of Pgcrypto: https://medium.com/@jianshi_94445/encrypt-decrypt-your-data-using-native-postgres-functions-with-sequelize-js-c04948d96833

Comment: Yes, you can use all type of queries, but without index. Is there any method like  query with index on encrypted column?